# How to add seconds to Bootstrap date time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using the Bootstrap datatimepicker (https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). It's great but it does not show or let the user select **seconds**.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({defaultDate: new Date()});
});


<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

So how to select seconds as well? And how to get seconds to show in the format? Currently it's `05/18/2017 1:26 PM`, I want `05/18/2017 1:26:40 PM`

In the [dev guide](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ContributorsGuide/), there is a `fillSeconds()` function  but I am not sure how to apply it here.

Comment: Look at the date formats listed here: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting the [format](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/) to the correct value from [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) and sideBySide:

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss A',
    sideBySide: true
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you explain what the `A` does?

Comment: in `DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss A`

Comment: @KevinB A stands for AM or PM. So instead of 13 you have 1PM. Could you upvote? thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
        defaultDate: new Date()});
}).fillseconds();
```

Try this way.