# Seconds is not showing in bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I've read some opened issue about this, but it didn't help me. I have also read the `moment.js` documentation but I don't know why it still not working. I just want to add the `seconds` to show when picking a datetime. Please see my code below:

```js
$(function(){

  $('#dateTimePicker').datetimepicker({
    format: "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss A"
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">


<input type="text" id="dateTimePicker" class="form-control">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try passing `useSeconds: true` as shown below. That should help.

The datetimepicker FAQ says that it uses the format option to decide what components to show. But then I found `useMinutes` and `useSeconds` options here: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Changelog/#2120.
(I know its not a very good place to document a feature, but .... let it be ;) )

```js
$(function(){

  $('#dateTimePicker').datetimepicker({
    format: "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss A",
    useSeconds: true
  });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">


<input type="text" id="dateTimePicker" class="form-control">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.4/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a great job.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this snippet,
Setting the [format](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/) to the correct value from [moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) and sideBySide:

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss A',
    sideBySide: true, 
    tooltips: {
      pickSecond: 'Pick Second'
     }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/master/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For more info please visit this - [How to add seconds to Bootstrap date time picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054324/how-to-add-seconds-to-bootstrap-date-time-picker)
Bootstrap3 DateTime picker - https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#viewdate

Comment: Can you identify what's wrong with my code? Because I've already set the format.

Comment: Sure let me check.

Comment: I've tried with your snippet, its working fine just check here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48634428/seconds-is-not-showing-in-bootstrap-datetimepicker/48635477?noredirect=1#comment84274582_48635477

Comment: @Jonjie, click on Expand snippet, then click on Run code snippet, then its displaying date-picker with seconds too, accept the answer if it works for you.

Comment: @Jonjie, Added this part of code to my snippet, please check - ` tooltips: {
          pickSecond: 'Pick Second'
         }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164599/discussion-between-bharadwaja-gummadi-and-jonjie).

Answer (score -1):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({format: "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss A"});
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you identify what's wrong with my code? Because I've already set the format.

Comment: Include jQuery ( jquery.min.js) in the starting then define $('#dateTimePicker').datetimepicker({
    format: "DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss A",
    useSeconds: true
  });

Comment: @Jonjie, Seconds will show in bootstrap datetimepicker in your code only after you include JQuery(jquery.min.js) in the starting of the files then define  $('#dateTimePicker').datetimepicker({ format.....